# bootstrap 3 rails 4 glyphicons not getting picked up in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, asset-pipeline

I am not using sass and I am not using the bootstrap gem.

in my bootstrap.css I have

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

I pre-compiled and commited (`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`)

The precompiled assets ended up in: public/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-.........

yet I get a `404  for domain.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf`

How can I get bootstrap.css to pickup the correct pre-compiled assets? I do not want to set th`e precompile = true` for production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps I had to do to fix the issue:

1. Override my bootstrap.css file moving the font declaration to a new application.css.scss file and using `asset_path` instead of a regular path:

In **bootstrap.css.scss**:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'));
  src: url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')) format('woff'), url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')) format('truetype'),
  url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular')) format('svg');
}
```

2. I had to add:   `config.assets.precompile += %w( *.eot *.svg *.ttf *.woff *.otf)` to my application.rb. From another answer I read that this is required if fonts are in vendor/assets otherwise they do not get picked up for pre-compilation
3. `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and a push